# Discord.py - change the default help command

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to change the help command to use a pagination version of help.

I understand that the following line of code removes the help command entirely:

```
bot.remove_command('help')
```

The docs/dicord.py server offer the following example as a way to change the default help command:

```
class MyHelpCommand(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    def get_command_signature(self, command):
        return '{0.clean_prefix}{1.qualified_name} {1.signature}'.format(self, command)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self._original_help_command = bot.help_command
        bot.help_command = MyHelpCommand()
        bot.help_command.cog = self

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.bot.help_command = self._original_help_command
```

I'm still a newbie in python, and I've only been learning rewrite for about 3 days - I'm struggling to find any working examples or an explanation that doesn't lead me back to the above code. I can't work out how to implement this into my own code - so my question is, could anyone provide further explaination into how this would be implemented using cogs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `help_command=None`. It delete default help command and you can create your help command. Example:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=None)

@bot.command()
async def help(context):
    await context.send("Custom help command")
```

If you don't set `help_command=None` and try to create your help command, you get this error: `discord.errors.ClientException: Command help is already registered`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to remove the command... It isn't good, using the (prefix)help commandname <- It wont appear then... If you want it embed you can do.

```py
class NewHelpName(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    async def send_pages(self):
        destination = self.get_destination()
        for page in self.paginator.pages:
            emby = discord.Embed(description=page)
            await destination.send(embed=emby)
client.help_command = NewHelpName()
```

The built in help command is of great use

Comment: Could you add some detail to this answer? Like an example on how to use this for this usecase? This improves reusability of this answer.