# Why does it say "The command help is already an existing command or alias." -Python

Tags: python, discord

Complete newbie here, I'm trying to make a discord bot but, I have a problem where it says "The command help is already an existing command or alias." whenever I run it.

```
import discord, random
from random import randint
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = ""

intents=discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready() :
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord !!')
    
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx) :
    await ctx.send('commands:')
    await ctx.send('1. Random - Random number')
    await ctx.send('2. Ping - say "Hello"')

@bot.command()
async def random(ctx) :
    await ctx.send(randint(1, 100))
    enter code here

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644195/discord-py-change-the-default-help-command

Comment: !help is a default command

Comment: there are certain keywords that you do not want to name functions as. `help` is one of those....  change `help` to `my_help` and also the same for `random` which is an `imported module` at the top....

Comment: @D.L but this changes the behavior of the bot he clearly wants to write !help and not !my_help

Comment: A solution would be ```@bot.command(name='help')``` for function ```my_help```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments help is a default command, but you can disable it
with
`help_command=None` in your commands.Bot function

```
import discord, random
from random import randint
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = ""

intents=discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents,help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready() :
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord !!')
    
@bot.command(name='help')
async def my_help(ctx) :
    await ctx.send('commands:')
    await ctx.send('1. Random - Random number')
    await ctx.send('2. Ping - say "Hello"')

@bot.command(name='random')
async def my_random(ctx) :
    await ctx.send(randint(1, 100))
    enter code here

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Maybe also rename the functions to avoid shadowing the prior meanings of `help` and `random` and specify the names explicitly, as you suggest in the question's comments?